# open existing postgresql store

Tags: python, postgresql, rdf, rdflib

I'm trying to write an RDF graph and store it on PostgreSQL (using Python's rdflib). I do this by opening the store which I have already created and opening a graph through this store. This process appears to work fine and I can write and query to that graph. However, every time I try and reopen the store it kills everything I previously wrote. This is how I open the store:

```
store = plugin.get('PostgreSQL', rdflib.store.Store)(identifier = db_id, configuration = configString)
```

Is there somewhere in this line where I need to put `create = False` or something?
Is there a way to load a store instead of using plugin.get?

Comment: I'm not really an RDFLib user, but there was a user having some trouble with PostgreSQL RDF stores who described a problem on the mailing list.  His final working code seems to be described in [this Google groups message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rdflib-dev/KYde6ECzaSE/MBZdStD8F4gJ).  Does it help at all?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, create defaults to True.  You will want to open the store using code like the following to connect to an existing store.  See the [README](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-postgresql) and the code @joshua-taylor references for examples.

```
g = Graph('PostgreSQL', identifier=db_id)
g.open(configString, create=False)
```

RDFLib developers now prefer the [RDFLib-SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-sqlalchemy) store and do not maintain the separate postgresql extension. You should consider switching to RDFLib-SQLAlchemy.